# How can I adjust this code so it only has one array but you make it into an object (so you can work with it as a JObject in the front end)?

Tags: php, arrays

Kinda new to PHP and cannot get this to work how I want it to.
I want to send my data as a object so I can work with it as a JObject in my frontend. 
I currently have two arrays (It works in the code, and I can recieve it as a JObject but it gives me two lists, two arrays) and I only want one of course.

This is the code:

```
        $contacts = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
        {
            $contact = array("ID" => $row['ProduktID'],
                             "Name" => $row['ProduktNamn'],
                         "Number" => $row['ProduktPris']);

            array_push($contacts, $contact);

        }

        echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));


}
```

Comment: It should be like that.. the code seems to be ok.. What's the current result?

Comment: I get the json how i want it but when I get my backend via a httpclient and write it out in the log, it loops out the results twice instead of 1.

Comment: I think this is another issue.. maybe the logger is not working properly?

Comment: I have been told by someone that it is because I use multiple arrays in the php-code and it has nothing to do with the log. I am clueless at this stage haha

Comment: When I want to reach for example ["Name"] in my frontend code I cannot.

Comment: you should do something like: `var data = JSON.parse(myHttpResponse); for (var obj of data) { console.log(obj.Name); }`

Comment: This is my current code (I use c#) var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost/GetStuff.php");

   var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

   var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (jsonResult ["Name"] + " is the value.");

Comment: You have the json_encode option in the wrong place. It should be: `json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: Same result with that change.

Comment: you use C# with PHP? why?

Comment: `jsonResult['results'][0]["Name"] + " is the value."`

Comment: That worked Matei!! Thanks mate. How could I get every "Name" out? Or is it just possible to get one at a time with numbers[0],[1], etc?

Comment: Your issue is on the front-end, you're showing us the backend. We can't help you with the information given.

Comment: @William.John you need to loop to get all the results.

Comment: Yes. I have one. But that is offtopic i guess. will create a new thread

Comment: you should edit your question and add the `C#` tag. its really not PHP

Comment: I will create a new thread i think as I go a bit offtopic. thx alot for the guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to C#. So the solution would be something like:

```
var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("localhost/GetStuff.php"); 
var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync (); 
var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

foreach (int element in jsonResult['results']) {
    ourList.Add (new Contact ((JArray) element);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (element['Name'] + " is the value.");
}
```

Comment: This works. Will create a new thread with a followup question. Thnks

Comment: Try it like I did.. I don't know c# very well but I suppose it will work

Comment: I cannot reach Name. You mean that I should maybe type (element ["name"]);?

Comment: I've just edited the answer.. I repeat that I don't know C# very well.. it's not my strong language, so I will stop suggesting any other solutions on it

Comment: It works. Thanks alot again Matei! Would give you another "thumbs up" if i could